# How to push my database contact list to mailjet automatically?

Tags: api, mailjet

I wanted to push or insert data to mailjet whenever there's a subscriber on my system.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add your entire list to mailjet, use `/contactslist/<list-id>/managemanycontact` http://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#contactslist_managemanycontacts